# Property doesn't exist on type

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm facing a strange problem. 
so my function `authenticateUser` returns and array like this

```
{
  success: false,
  msg: "invalid password"
}
```

But when I'm trying to check if the `success == false` I get the error
that there is no such property on type Objects

```
 this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data=>{
  if(data.success){//here need to check response for success
    console.log(data)
    this.authService.storeUserData(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
  }else{
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
```

I've tried to use examples from other tutorials, but still no solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do this:

Option 1 use type `any`:

```
this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe((data: any)=>{
  if(data.success){//here need to check response for success
    console.log(data)
    this.authService.storeUserData(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
  }else{
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

Or doing it strongly typed `{success: boolean, msg: string}` or create a interface of this type:

```
this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe((data: {success: boolean, msg: string}) =>{
  if(data.success){//here need to check response for success
    console.log(data)
    this.authService.storeUserData(data);
    this.router.navigate(['/user']);
  }else{
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Angular but it's because data isn't typed properly, you can fix this by casting or by a type-guard.

```
const hasSuccess = (something: any): something is {success: boolean} {
     return "success" in something;
}

if(hasSuccess(data) && data.success) ...
```